# Young's double slit experiment - fringe width

Tags: optics, terminology, double-slit-experiment

What is the main difference between fringe width and fringe breadth?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between fringe width and fringe breadth in Young double slit experiment. In Young double silt experiment you can see straight fringe near central fringe. So for a line fringe width or breadth are same.